# How do I reset this variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to reset the variable `a` in my program.

What's the program about? It catches some IDs from a scanner and transforms them into a receipt.

How the code works? This part of the code that I'm showing you catches those IDs and fills them into a table, and when I press a button, in this case "btnRecibo", it cleans all the table data and the total number of IDs.

But here's the problem. When I clean all the data, the variable `a` keeps data saved in the background (the total) and it can't be reset along with the table. All the table data is clean, but the total isn't. So I want to reset it.

The code:

```
var a = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("change","#txtInput",function(){
        $("#contenido").append("<tr><td>"+$("#txtInput").val()+"</td></tr>");
        a += 1;
        var str = 'Total Bianuales: '
        $('p').html(str + a);
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#btnRecibo", function(){
        $("#tablaB > tbody").html("");
        var str = 'Total Bianuales: '
        $('p').html(str + "");
    })
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for `a = 0`?

Comment: put `a = 0` on click of `#btnRecibo` and check again

Comment: You don't need two different `document ready` functions. You can combine them into one.

Comment: It works guys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "#btnRecibo", function(){
            $("#tablaB > tbody").html("");
            var str = 'Total Bianuales: '
            $('p').html(str + "");
            //here
            a= 0;
        }

        )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other variables are "reset" because they're in the anonymous functions you have there. `a` is in the outer scope, so it's available throughout. If you're using it later, you can set it to 0 in your #btnRecibo onclick. If you're not, you could unset it with `delete`, but that's bad practice and there's no need if you're not using it anymore since it'll be garbage collected automatically.